# Angular JS and Ionic - Error on $http.post, help me understand

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to upload a file from an iOS, but I have an unexpected error. This is my HTML:

```
      <div ng-repeat="photo in vendordata.galerias" class="elemento">
        <div style="z-index: 10;">
          <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{photo.url}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="" style="text-align: center;">
          <button class="" href="#" ng-show="photo.borrar">Eliminar</button>
          <button class="" href="#" ng-click="subirFoto($index+1)" ng-hide="photo.borrar">Subir foto</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The controller methods:

```
$scope.subirFoto = function(identificador){
    $scope.elementoSek = identificador;
    console.log("IMG src seleccionado:"+$scope.elementoSek);
    $scope.getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);
  };
  $scope.getPhoto = function (source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
  };
  function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    // Uncomment to view the image file URI

    // Get image handle
    var previo = $scope.vendordata.galerias[$scope.elementoSek].url;



    var file = imageURI;
    var uploadUrl = CLOSER_SERVER.url+'/upload_vendor';
    var uploadResult = fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, $scope.elementoSek, Session.getId(), 'vendor');

    console.log(uploadResult);
    if(uploadResult.response == "200"){
      $scope.vendordata.galerias[$scope.elementoSek].url = imageURI;
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  }
```

And the service fileUpload:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, numero, sessionIde, typePic){
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('file', file);
         var data = {
          session : sessionIde,
          num_foto: numero,
          type : typePic
         };

        fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .then(function(data){
          console.log("response ok: "+JSON.stringify(data));
          return JSON.stringify(data);
        }, function(){
          console.log("response fail");
          return "error subiendo archivo";
        });
    }
}]);
```

What this does? In a image gallery of 6 elements, we click "Upload" (Subir) button, then the iOS image gallery is loaded for picking an image. When I pick an image, the image URI is sent to the fileUpload service. With the method uploadFIleToUrl() I send it to the server with `$http.post`. In this moment it throws an odd error I cannot understand:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'uploadResult.response')
>
> callbackFromNativecordova.js:306
>
> (función anónima)cordova.js:1102
>
> nativeEvalAndFetchcordova.js:1110
>
> nativeCallbackcordova.js:1099
>
> (función anónima)index.html:1

Using console.log I had checked that the error happens in the service fileUpload between line `fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));` and the line `console.log("response ok: "+JSON.stringify(data));`

What is this error???

Comment: have you debugged, and checked whats the response from your post?

Comment: Don't forget iOS9 Transport Security Policy. You need to tell it about any server URL you are communicating with

Comment: I have checked the response of the post, is printed with `console.log("response ok: "+JSON.stringify(data));`and it gives me OK. As it has to be. But just before the response comes the error. It is something strange.

Comment: @Tokn, the Security Policy is set, is not the first $http post and get that the app uses, but this is the one which throws an error.

Comment: can you create plnkr?

Comment: You have this line: console.log(uploadResult). What does uploadResult look like in the console?

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal have you try angular.toJson(data); ?

Comment: I think you might be trying to use uploadResult before you've returned anything from your service

Comment: I would be difficult to create a plunkr due to the size of the app and the confidentiality agreement I have with my client. The line `console.log(uploadResult)` is not being executed, the execution stops just before.

Comment: Your first error is "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'uploadResult.response')". Doesn't this come from the line "if(uploadResult.response == "200"){" ?

Comment: @prashant its the same result with `angular.toJson(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the error occurs before the HTTP post?

Seems like in case of failure on fileUpload service, you return a string, but when you try to access the result, you always treat as a JSON object:

```
.then(function(data){
      console.log("response ok: "+JSON.stringify(data));
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    }, function(){
      console.log("response fail");
      return "error subiendo archivo";
    });
```

You need some validation here:

```
if(angular.isObject(uploadResult) && uploadResult.response == "200"){
  $scope.vendordata.galerias[$scope.elementoSek].url = imageURI;
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

You could make use of [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), even if you can't/don't want to use the directives, you still can use de upload service.

Good luck!

Comment: I am going to review that. Maybe you are in the way. Give 5 mins

Comment: You was totally right. The validation solved some, the data returned by the server was not the object I was thinking and the error was in the inf condition clause.

Comment: I will see a bit of ng-file-upload, thanks a lot to all of you.